# Spring Boot interceptor release static resources

Tags: java, spring-boot

I implemented the interceptor function in WebMvcConfigurerAdapter as the following:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    registry.addInterceptor(new LoginInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**").excludePathPatterns(excludeUrls);

    super.addInterceptors(registry);
}
```

However, all the static resources such as Bootstrap and images are also intercepted. I think the "/**" path here cause this problem. Is there any method to release those static resources?

Comment: Whats in excludeUrls?

Comment: login and register urls.

Comment: By adding /** in addPathPatterns(), you are restricting all paths from your application base path. Try excluding Bootstrap and image paths by adding image paths in excludePaths  "/images/**".